# Doesn't work &-suffix in Sass 3.4.5

Tags: ruby, sass, phpstorm

I decide to change LESS to Sass and I use to use long classes line `class="main-content__list-item__link"`. It's very easy in LESS: you just & and get smth like that:

```
.main {
    &-content {
        &__list-item {
            &__link {...}
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work with PhpStorm and ruby. Work everything except this: I can't use `&-suffix`, although it seems that it has to be possible from 3.3.0 version (I have 3.4.5). But - nope, my IDE throw an error about 'unexpected identifier'.
Prepros can do it, but in PhpStorm this lines marks as a mistake. Ruby doesn't understand `&-suffix` - no version of all existing, I was trying.

So I need to give up and just use LESS or there is some possibility to use `&-suffix` in .sass/.scss files? Don't you know?

Comment: Your code works on http://sassmeister.com for 3.3.14 and 3.4.4 (BTW, `&-` is a prefix, not a suffix)

Comment: 1) What IDE version is that? 2) screenshot of the error, please.

Comment: I have the same problem. I work with phpstorm 7 and SASS 3.4.20

Answer (score 2):

SASS 3.3.* support is included in PHPStorm 8 - see [WEB-9702](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9702). No errors are reported for your code snippet in PHPStorm 8.0.1

Answer (score 0):

That feature is/was not yet available in SASS, but it is coming. See [this issue](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/286).

Try the latest SASS version to check if it works by now.

Comment: According to the [CHANGELOG](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html#330_7_march_2014), it was introduced in 3.3.0: *"The parent selector, `&`, can be used with an identifier suffix. For example, `&-suffix` and `&_suffix` are now legal."*

Answer (score -1):

For phpStorm 7 in your fileWatcher check "Trigger watcher regardless of syntax errors"